# "the cost of water" would increase "pumping costs"? or "pumping costs" would increase "the cost of water".?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> In the face of the upcoming water supply crisis, a number of grandiose schemes have been developed to transport vast quantities of water by canal or pipeline from the Mississippi, the Missouri, or the Arkansas rivers. Unfortunately, **the cost of water obtained through any of these schemes would increase pumping costs at least tenfold**, making the cost of irrigated agricultural products from the region uncompetitive on the national and international markets. (From TOEFL exam)

I do not think the meaning of the bold sentence makes sense, why "the cost of water" would increase "pumping costs"? I think, logically, it should have been "pumping costs" would increase "the cost of water".
Please help me understand it, I may misread the meaning of the original sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. It doesn't make sense as it is. If the given pieces were assembled like this, it would make sense:

"Unfortunately, pumping costs would increase the cost of water obtained through any of these schemes at least tenfold, making the cost of irrigated agricultural products from the region uncompetitive..."